# How to extracting values looping over nested .nxml files in R

Tags: r, xml, nxml

I am using pubmed data in `.nxml` format
I have several categorized folders by topic (each contains 100-300 .nxml files). I wrote the following code to extract the abstarct from one single file and save it as a data frame:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse("Genetics_2011_Aug_188(4)_799-808.nxml")
plant.df <- as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(doc,"//abstract",function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))))
```

which works for one file.

My question is when I use:

```
files <- (list.files(pattern = "\\.nxml$"))
```

to loop over files in one folder it saved the files as a character so I couldn't use `xmlParse` because of the type.(I got : `Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:`)

How can I loop over the files or in some other words automate the process?
Thanks.

Updated:

```
    library(XML)
files <- c(list.files(pattern = "\\.nxml$",full.names=TRUE))
#print(typeof(files))
for (i in files)
  {
  allfiles <- xmlParse(i)
  abstract.df <- as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(allfiles,"//abstract",function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))))
  }
print(abstract.df)

sink("outtext.txt") 
lapply(abstract.df, print) 
sink()
```

Comment: I think `xmlParse()` may be thinking the string content is actually XML content. Try using the `full.names=TRUE` parameter to `list.files()` to see if that helps `xmlParse()` disambiguate the content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should paste your actual code being used for the looping.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I found the solution, Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You should prbly add it as an answer so others can learn from it or possibly delete the question if it was a simple mistake that others are unlikely to make.